# Create dynamic links in block

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

How do you create a block with multiple dynamic links? If the url is `http://www.domain.com/series/bomberman-jetters/node/add/gallery/82` then the 82 is varied depending what node your viewing.

Also another link `http://www.domain.com/series/bomberman-jetters/node/add/gallery/82` again the 82 is varied. I want these 2 dynamics link as a button link in a block. How can I do this? This is for Drupal 7

Comment: `arg(5)` ? .....

Comment: I'm not programmer can you please give the full code?